# Flutter: I need help in importing my online data from online MYSQL to offline SQLITE

Tags: flutter, dart

I have and online database which I am connected to using RESP API to featch data and display in my flutter based App.
I want to be able to download the data from the online database and store it on the offline database which is SQLIITE.

I have been able to fetch the data from the online database and I am also able to display it on the interface of my app.

Now, I need help with storing the data to local storage  which MYSQLite
So its more like syncing online data to offline.